# Using the parskip package, I find the space between subtitles ugly

Tags: spacing, sectioning, parskip

I recently started using the [`parskip`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package. However, I find the space between the ending of text and the next subtitle too small. Similarly, I find the space between the Subtitle and the subsubtitle too big. Also the space between the subsubtitle and the next text is too big.

What is the most preferred way to change this, remembering I am using the `parskip` package?

Comment: The better alternative is to use a class that takes care of a proper `\parskip` as mentioned in the »[parskip](http://texdoc.net/pkg/parskip)« manual. The »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)« bundle offers such classes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I wish to keep things as simple as possible. Can I continue to use the parskip package but simply tweek the settings? If so, what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Using a class the does job sounds simpler for me than any manual tweak of settings.

Comment: I find ugly those documents which use a non zero parskip. `;-)`

Answer (score 8):

> Patient: Doctor, it hurts when I do *this* ! Doctor: Then don't *do*
>   that!

To get a better version of `parskip`-like spacing, use a KOMA-Script document class with the parskip option.  Assuming you are writing an article or other simple document, just use this:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
```

Then experiment with `parksip=half` or `parskip=full+` and see whether your document looks better.  If you want more details read the excellent and detailed (perhaps too detailed :-) KOMA-Script documentation on CTAN.

If you can't or don't want to do that, then you will have to resort to some good old plain TeX.  All that the `parskip` package does is to set the `\parskip` and `\parindent` parameters. So you can do this yourself if you want.  Try adding these lines to your preamble instead of `\usepackage{parskip}`:

```
\parskip=12pt 
\parindent=0pt
```

**BUT** there are some issues with doing this.  First other parts of TeX may make assumptions about the values;  in plain TeX for example the `\narrower` macro assumes that `\parindent` is positive; or the page breaking algorithm might give you slightly nicer pages if there was some stretchability in the `\parskip` glue.

Secondly for any serious work, you should think carefully about the typography.  With a blank line between paragraphs, you probably want to have the last line of each paragraph reasonably full so you may want to fiddle with `\parfillskip` as well.  And the spacing around your headings and displays may not look so good,  so you may want to start customising the headings and the spacing around displays.

At this point you might consider writing your own package.

Or using the nice simple option that KOMA-Script already provides.