# Pandoc: No vertical space before/after environments

Tags: pandoc

When I render a pandoc-markdown document to PDF that contains LaTeX environments, e.g. this one

```
We come now to the main theorem of our article.
\begin{thm}
   There exists something that doesn't exist.
\end{thm}
This follows trivially by induction.
```

then there is no vertical space between the line "We come ..." and the theorem environment (whereas positive vertical space is inserted when rendering normally using LaTeX).

Here, the `thm`-environment is defined as usual (assuming the package `amsthm` is included) by

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
```

How can I make pandoc insert vertical space around environments (without having to insert them manually)?

**Edit:** Here's the output of `pandoc -D latex`:

```
\documentclass[$if(fontsize)$$fontsize$,$endif$$if(lang)$$babel-lang$,$endif$$if(papersize)$$papersize$paper,$endif$$for(classoption)$$classoption$$sep$,$endfor$]{$documentclass$}
$if(beamerarticle)$
\usepackage{beamerarticle} % needs to be loaded first
$endif$
$if(fontfamily)$
\usepackage[$for(fontfamilyoptions)$$fontfamilyoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$fontfamily$}
$else$
\usepackage{lmodern}
$endif$
$if(linestretch)$
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{$linestretch$}
$endif$
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[$if(fontenc)$$fontenc$$else$T1$endif$]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
$if(euro)$
  \usepackage{eurosym}
$endif$
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
$for(fontfamilies)$
  \newfontfamily{$fontfamilies.name$}[$fontfamilies.options$]{$fontfamilies.font$}
$endfor$
$if(euro)$
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
$endif$
$if(mainfont)$
    \setmainfont[$for(mainfontoptions)$$mainfontoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$mainfont$}
$endif$
$if(sansfont)$
    \setsansfont[$for(sansfontoptions)$$sansfontoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$sansfont$}
$endif$
$if(monofont)$
    \setmonofont[Mapping=tex-ansi$if(monofontoptions)$,$for(monofontoptions)$$monofontoptions$$sep$,$endfor$$endif$]{$monofont$}
$endif$
$if(mathfont)$
    \setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[$for(mathfontoptions)$$mathfontoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$mathfont$}
$endif$
$if(CJKmainfont)$
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \setCJKmainfont[$for(CJKoptions)$$CJKoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$CJKmainfont$}
$endif$
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage[$for(microtypeoptions)$$microtypeoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url} % url is loaded by hyperref
$if(verbatim-in-note)$
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
$endif$
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
$if(colorlinks)$
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{color} % color is loaded by hyperref
$endif$
\hypersetup{
$if(title-meta)$
            pdftitle={$title-meta$},
$endif$
$if(author-meta)$
            pdfauthor={$author-meta$},
$endif$
$if(keywords)$
            pdfkeywords={$for(keywords)$$keywords$$sep$, $endfor$},
$endif$
$if(colorlinks)$
            colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=$if(linkcolor)$$linkcolor$$else$Maroon$endif$,
            citecolor=$if(citecolor)$$citecolor$$else$Blue$endif$,
            urlcolor=$if(urlcolor)$$urlcolor$$else$Blue$endif$,
$else$
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
$endif$
            breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
$if(verbatim-in-note)$
\VerbatimFootnotes % allows verbatim text in footnotes
$endif$
$if(geometry)$
\usepackage[$for(geometry)$$geometry$$sep$,$endfor$]{geometry}
$endif$
$if(lang)$
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[shorthands=off,$for(babel-otherlangs)$$babel-otherlangs$,$endfor$main=$babel-lang$]{babel}
$if(babel-newcommands)$
  $babel-newcommands$
$endif$
\else
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[$polyglossia-lang.options$]{$polyglossia-lang.name$}
$for(polyglossia-otherlangs)$
  \setotherlanguage[$polyglossia-otherlangs.options$]{$polyglossia-otherlangs.name$}
$endfor$
\fi
$endif$
$if(natbib)$
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{$if(biblio-style)$$biblio-style$$else$plainnat$endif$}
$endif$
$if(biblatex)$
\usepackage[$if(biblio-style)$style=$biblio-style$,$endif$$for(biblatexoptions)$$biblatexoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{biblatex}
$for(bibliography)$
\addbibresource{$bibliography$}
$endfor$
$endif$
$if(listings)$
\usepackage{listings}
$endif$
$if(lhs)$
\lstnewenvironment{code}{\lstset{language=Haskell,basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}}{}
$endif$
$if(highlighting-macros)$
$highlighting-macros$
$endif$
$if(tables)$
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
% Fix footnotes in tables (requires footnote package)
\IfFileExists{footnote.sty}{\usepackage{footnote}\makesavenoteenv{long table}}{}
$endif$
$if(graphics)$
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
$endif$
$if(links-as-notes)$
% Make links footnotes instead of hotlinks:
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}
$endif$
$if(strikeout)$
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% avoid problems with \sout in headers with hyperref:
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\renewcommand{\sout}{}}
$endif$
$if(indent)$
$else$
\IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
\usepackage{parskip}
}{% else
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
}
$endif$
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
$if(numbersections)$
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{$if(secnumdepth)$$secnumdepth$$else$5$endif$}
$else$
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
$endif$
$if(subparagraph)$
$else$
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
$endif$
$if(dir)$
\ifxetex
  % load bidi as late as possible as it modifies e.g. graphicx
  $if(latex-dir-rtl)$
  \usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}
  $else$
  \usepackage{bidi}
  $endif$
\fi
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \TeXXeTstate=1
  \newcommand{\RL}[1]{\beginR #1\endR}
  \newcommand{\LR}[1]{\beginL #1\endL}
  \newenvironment{RTL}{\beginR}{\endR}
  \newenvironment{LTR}{\beginL}{\endL}
\fi
$endif$

% set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother

$for(header-includes)$
$header-includes$
$endfor$

$if(title)$
\title{$title$$if(thanks)$\thanks{$thanks$}$endif$}
$endif$
$if(subtitle)$
\providecommand{\subtitle}[1]{}
\subtitle{$subtitle$}
$endif$
$if(author)$
\author{$for(author)$$author$$sep$ \and $endfor$}
$endif$
$if(institute)$
\providecommand{\institute}[1]{}
\institute{$for(institute)$$institute$$sep$ \and $endfor$}
$endif$
\date{$date$}

\begin{document}
$if(title)$
\maketitle
$endif$
$if(abstract)$
\begin{abstract}
$abstract$
\end{abstract}
$endif$

$for(include-before)$
$include-before$

$endfor$
$if(toc)$
{
$if(colorlinks)$
\hypersetup{linkcolor=$if(toccolor)$$toccolor$$else$black$endif$}
$endif$
\setcounter{tocdepth}{$toc-depth$}
\tableofcontents
}
$endif$
$if(lot)$
\listoftables
$endif$
$if(lof)$
\listoffigures
$endif$
$body$

$if(natbib)$
$if(bibliography)$
$if(biblio-title)$
$if(book-class)$
\renewcommand\bibname{$biblio-title$}
$else$
\renewcommand\refname{$biblio-title$}
$endif$
$endif$
\bibliography{$for(bibliography)$$bibliography$$sep$,$endfor$}

$endif$
$endif$
$if(biblatex)$
\printbibliography$if(biblio-title)$[title=$biblio-title$]$endif$

$endif$
$for(include-after)$
$include-after$

$endfor$
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is not normal for LaTeX. How are thm defined? Note: we need to know how they are defined at the LaTeX end, not the markdown end.

Comment: @daleif It is typeset normally in LaTeX. But when I compile it to PDF *using pandoc*, it comes out weird. P.S.: I've added the definition of `thm`.

Comment: You need to provide a full (but minimal)  example of the type of LaTeX code you end up with being generated by pandoc. Otherwise the rest of us cannot help you.

Comment: That is not a LaTeX file, all those special `$...$` are not LaTeX

Comment: We need to see the output of `pandoc -s -o your-file.tex`; the default template contents is already known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cause of Problem:** As it turned out, the culprit was the inclusion of the `parskip`-package by the default LaTeX template, right here:

```
$if(indent)$
$else$
\IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
\usepackage{parskip}
}{% else
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
}
$endif$
```

Even though in theory (cf. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133171/)) the parskip package should do nothing beyond setting `\parskip` and `\parident`, it seems to seriously mess things up.

**Solution(s):** There are at least two ways to circumvent this problem:

1. Set the `indent` variable:

   ```
   pandoc --variable=indent -o file.pdf file.md
   ```
2. Use a custom template: First export the default template

   ```
   pandoc -D latex > template.tex
   ```

   Then remove the problematic section of template mentioned above

   ```
   vim template.tex
   ```

   Finally, use `template.tex` instead of the default template:

   ```
   pandoc --template=template.tex -o file.pdf file.md
   ```

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Does `kpsewhich parskip.sty` show that the `parskip` package is installed? I suspect that it's missing, hence LaTeX is instead using the `\setlength` lines.

Comment: Yes, `kpsewhich parskip.sty` shows that `parskip` is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are adding the theorem environment through `header-includes` and using the default template. In that situation, it will be rendered normally, with vertical space before and after:

[image: Pandoc theorem]

```
pandoc -o thm.pdf << EOT

---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsthm}
- \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
---

We come now to the main theorem of our article.

\begin{thm}
   There exists something that doesn't exist.
\end{thm}

This follows trivially by induction.

EOT
```

Comment: I did precisely that, but pandoc still doesn't add spaces!

Comment: Do you have different output when using the command as illustrated above? If so, make sure that you're using the most recent version of Pandoc and that you don't have a custom LaTeX template in `~/.local/share/pandoc` or `~/.pandoc`.

Comment: The folders `~/.local/share/pandoc` and `~/.pandoc` don't even exist. When I typeset the example you provide above, there is no vertical space between "We come ..." and the beginning of the `thm`-environment. My pandoc version is `1.19.2.4`.

Comment: Have you tried updating to the most recent versions of Pandoc and TeX Live?

Comment: I've tried it with version `2.2.1` of pandoc: unfortunately, no such luck. Even this newer version still doesn't put any vertical space for your example above.